# Please explain these codes

Tags: java, sockets

What is this? outSocket/inSocket is socket or PrintWriter/BufferedReader object?

```
toServer = new Socket(args[0], SERVERPORT);

//open socket for writing. But what is after the new key word????            
PrintWriter outSocket = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(toServer.getOutputStream()),true);

//open socket for reading. 
BufferedReader inSocket = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(toServer.getInputStream()));
```

Comment: It's exactly what it looks like....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a server using sockets.

`outSocket` is the object to where the server will write output and communicate with the clients and `inSocket` is the object from where the server will receive the clients' requests.

There's not much more to say since the code you've posted is too generic.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Study this: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Streams/ProgIOStreams/

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your code is setting up a `PrintWriter` and a `BufferedReader` to be able to use high level method rather than the low level methods supplied by `Input`/`OutputStream`.

You should have a look to the javadoc for all those classes and come back with more specific question.